# My alarm key box dont work on a 1996 toyato Avalon

Tags: electrical, toyota, fob, avalon

I replace the battery the key box, and It still doesn't work.
Its a factory alarm in my car. Can I get a replacement for this, Due to the year of the car. 1996 Toyota Avalon.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have a second key fob? If so, does it work?

Comment: No. I just purchase the car last month @ an Action. I only had the one key to start the car and the alarm box.

Comment: Did the current key fob ever work for you?

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about.  I only had the one key to start the car and the alarm box. (the remote for the alarm and it doesn't work ..with a new battery)

Comment: I know what you're talking about. I never had a key fob.

Comment: What do you mean "Alarm Box"? I have never heard the term. If you are referring to the little device with buttons used to lock/unlock doors and arm/disarm the alarm, that is called a key fob. (http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/key-fob) If you are referring to something else, please explain or provide a picture.

Answer (score 1):

The key fob probably needs to be programmed to the car again. The below procedure should work for 2003-2008 Avalons.

**Procedure To Program Toyota Wireless Remote Transmitters:**

Begin with: The driver's door open and unlocked. Key out of the ignition.

1. Insert and remove the key from the ignition switch 2 times within 5
   seconds.

*NOTE: Steps 2 and 3 should be performed within 40 seconds.*

2. Close and open driver's door TWICE.
3. Insert the key in the ignition and remove it.

*NOTE: Steps 4 - 6 should be performed within 40 seconds.*

4. Close and open the driver's door twice.
5. Insert the key in the ignition.
6. Close the door.
7. Turn the ignition switch from "Lock" to "On" and back to "Lock" 1 time.
8. Remove the key from the ignition.
9. To confirm you are in program mode, the power locks will now cycle "lock" to "unlock" 1 time.

*NOTE: If Confirmation or Prohibition modes have been selected, opening the door will complete the procedure.*

10. To Add a remote, do the following within 40 seconds

> Procedure Lock confirmation:
>
> A. Press both car transmitter Lock and Unlock buttons simultaneously
>   between 1 and 1.5 seconds and release.
>
> B. Within 3 seconds of step A, press the transmitter Lock button for
>   more than 1 second and release.
>
> If the keyless entry remote transmitter has been successfully
>   programmed, the power locks will cycle "lock" to "unlock" once at this
>   time.
>
> If there are problems with the remote transmitter or the procedure up
>   to this point, the locks will cycle twice. If this occurs, verify that
>   you have received the correct transmitter, and then repeat the above
>   procedure.
>
> C. If multiple remotes are to be reprogrammed, repeat steps A and B.

11. Open the driver's door to conclude programming mode.

Source - [How to program Toyota Keyless Remote Keyfob](https://www.carandtruckremotes.com/how-to-program-toyota-replacement-keyless-entry-control-remotes.html)

*Note: Some steps were removed to make these instructions specific to what you are trying to do. More detailed programming instructions are at the link.*